# JSONX to JSON transformation

Tags: xml, json, arrays, jsonx

I have some XML data dumped from my database and I need to re-format it into JSON. I am using an IBM DataPower database, so I actually need to transform that XML to [JSONx](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v3r8m1/topic/xs40/convertingbetweenjsonandjsonx05.htm) and then use IBM's default translator, which automatically translates JSONx to JSON.

I am having difficulty in defining the elements of a JSONx array. Here's what I'm currently trying:

## XML

```xml
<sql result="success">
    <row>
        <column>
            <name>Prod</name>
            <value>Acura</value>
        </column>
        <column>
            <name>Color</name>
            <value>SILVER</value>
        </column>
        <column>
            <name>Prod</name>
            <value>Accord</value>
        </column>
        <column>
            <name>Color</name>
            <value>Gold</value>
        </column>
    </row>
</sql>
```

## Desired JSON output

```json
{"Category" : [
    {“prod”: “Acura”, "Color" : “Silver”},
    {“prod”: “Accord”, "Color" : “Gold”}
    ],
    "Status" : “Success”
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get `prod` and `color` to be part of the same JSON object. Instead, I am getting output like this:

```json
{"Category": [{
    "ID":    [
        ": Acura",
        ": Accord"
        ],
    "NAME":    [
        ": SILVER",
        ": Gold"
        ]
}]}
```

Here's the JSONx code that I'm using that produces the problematic JSON:

```xml
<json:object
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="Category">
        <json:object>
            <xsl:for-each select="//column">
                <xsl:variable name="colName" select="name" />
                <xsl:if test="$colName = 'Prod'">
                    <json:string name="Prod">:
                        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
                    </json:string>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$colName = 'Color'">
                    <json:string name="Color">:
                        <xsl:value-of select="value" />
                    </json:string>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

I can tell that the `<xsl:for-each>` tag is going through one condition and creating a JSON object in the loop, but I don't understand how to create the JSON object *after* it gets the values of both `color` and `prod`. How can I make sure that those values are parsed correctly?

Comment: Careful with those smart quotes..

Answer (score 2):

Hi I got the answer,I have tried multiple possibilities,This is one of the posibility,I will get the output like i mentioned in that question

```
<json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="Categories">

<xsl:for-each select="sql/row">
<json:object>
<xsl:for-each select="column">
<xsl:variable name="colName" select="name" />
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$colName = 'PROD ">
<json:string name="name">  <xsl:value-of select="value"/></json:string>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$colName = 'NAME'">
<json:string name="ID">  <xsl:value-of select="value"/></json:string>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</json:object>
</xsl:for-each>
</json:array>
   </json:object>
```

output

```
{"Categories": [
      {
      "prod": "Acura",
      "color": "SILVER"
   },
      {
      "prod": "Accord",
      "color": "Gold"
   }
]}
```

Comment: +1 ... you prove that i was wrong on that `it will drive you to unreasonable complexity` ... don't forget to accept your answer :)

Comment: haha no man..your help is appreciated..infact i got the answer by observing yours..:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to work more on the `database to xml` parsing, to get an xml like this:

```
<product-list>
    <product>
        <name>Acura</name>
        <color>SILVER</color>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Accord</name>
        <color>Gold</color>
    </product>
</product-list>
```

this way will be more achievable to parse it as you want.

The xml you showing, maybe is possible to do this but it will drive you to unreasonable complexity ... i think

edit: my programming environment is not ready for something like this ... so let me know for the results

```
<json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="Category">
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="prod"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></json:string>
                <json:string name="Color"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></json:string>
            </json:object>
        <xsl:for-each>
    <json:array>
</json:object>
```

or this way

```
<json:object xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:array name="Category">
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <xsl:text>{<xsl:text>
                <json:string name="prod"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></json:string>
                <json:string name="Color"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></json:string>
            <xsl:text>}<xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each>
    <json:array>
</json:object>
```

i think the first is fine ... in case where the object needs name, choose the last.

Comment: Please tell me how to parse the XML that you have mentioned and print it it in JSON format like i mentioned